# Greenplum not allowing to cancel long running queries

Tags: sql, database, pgadmin, greenplum

There is a insert query which is loading data into table A from from table B .

Table B is having 3000 million records.

The query is running since 4 hours and after that if the user is forcefully cancelling it from the pivotal greenplum command center.
it's still running in the backend.

tried running the below commands:

```
pg_cancel_backend(pid)/pg_terminate_backend(pid)
```

both are returning true with no effect in real time.

how to deal with this , is restarting the db is the only option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check for error in the pg_log and try pstack the process on segment host to see what it is doing